# How to send request to endpoint with Boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to list items in a S3 container with the following code.

```
import boto.s3
from boto.s3.connection import OrdinaryCallingFormat

conn = boto.connect_s3(calling_format=OrdinaryCallingFormat())
mybucket = conn.get_bucket('Container001')

for key in mybucket.list():
    print key.name.encode('utf-8')
```

Then I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    mybucket = conn.get_bucket('Container001')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 370, in get_bucket
bucket.get_all_keys(headers, maxkeys=0)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 358, in get_all_keys
'', headers, **params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 325, in _get_all
response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 301 Moved Permanently
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
PermanentRedirectThe bucket you are attempting to access  must be addressed using the  specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.99EBDB9DE3B6E3AF
Container001
<HostId>5El9MLfgHZmZ1UNw8tjUDAl+XltYelHu6d/JUNQsG3OaM70LFlpRchEJi9oepeMy</HostId><Endpoint>Container001.s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint></Error>
```

I tried to search for how to send requests to the specified end point, but couldn't find useful information.

How do I avoid this error?

Comment: Do you still get the error if you try `conn = boto.connect_s3()` without the `calling_format`?

Comment: That gives me a different error:
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/443) out.

Comment: @Drewness
According to that page this is a bug. However that thread is 9 months old.

Comment: Yes and yes. You could try the branch they suggest as they were unable to dup the issue.

Comment: @Drewness
Excuse my naivety. Is wal-e an alternative to boto?

Comment: Not exactly. Have a look [here](https://github.com/wal-e/wal-e/pull/3).

Comment: One reason you might get this error is that the bucket is located in a particular region, say us-west-2, and you are trying to connect to the bucket via the generic S3 endpoint.  Normally this should work because there is DNS magic to redirect you but if you are using path-style addressing (as OrdinaryCallingFormat does) that magic doesn't work.  So, you could try to create a connection to the region the bucket lives in via ``import boto.s3``, ``conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region('<region_name>')``.

Answer (score 10):

As @garnaat mentioned and @Rico [answered in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22462419/3162882) `connect_to_region` works with `OrdinaryCallingFormat`:

```
conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region(
   region_name = '<your region>',
   aws_access_key_id = '<access key>',
   aws_secret_access_key = '<secret key>',
   calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat()
   )
bucket = conn.get_bucket('<bucket name>')
```

Answer (score 0):

in terminal run

> nano ~/.boto

if there is some configs try to comment or rename file and connect again. (it helps me)

http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html

there is boto config file directories. take a look one by one and clean them all, it will work by default configs. also configs may be in .bash_profile, .bash_source... 
I guess you must allow only KEY-SECRET

also try to use

> calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat()