# how to upload the file under different region of AWS-s3 bucket using python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, iot

```
import boto
import boto.s3
import sys
from boto.s3.key import Key

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
bucket_name="s3 bucket_name"
conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

bucket=conn.get_bucket(bucket_name,validate=True,headers=None)s

testfile = "file_path"
print ('Uploading %s to Amazon S3 bucket %s' % (testfile, bucket_name))

def percent_cb(complete, total):
    sys.stdout.write('.')
    sys.stdout.flush()

k = Key(bucket)
k.key = 'mytestfile.csv'
k.set_contents_from_filename(testfile,
    cb=percent_cb, num_cb=10)
```

- this is the program which i used to upload the **.csv** file in s3 bucket,its was working in expected manner if the region which i selected is **US East (N. Virginia)** but i need to upload the file under **'US East (Ohio)'** region. if i trying to do it i'm getting following exception  **boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request**.if anyone having a solution for this,share with me.

Comment: You need to use `boto.s3.connect_to_region` method. Details can be found in this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454559/unable-to-connect-aws-s3-bucket-using-boto

Comment: i was tried it but it's not working from me.if have any reference.share with me.

Comment: Can you share the code you tried and the error you received?

Comment: i followed the link which you shared with me it's working in expected manner.code is here thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import boto
import sys
from boto.s3.key import Key
import boto.s3.connection

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '<access_key>'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '<secert_key>'
Bucketname = 'bucket_name' 


conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region('us-east-2',
       aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
       aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
       is_secure=True,               # uncomment if you are not using ssl
       calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
       )
bucket = conn.get_bucket(Bucketname)

testfile = "filename"
print ('Uploading %s to Amazon S3 bucket %s' % 
   (testfile, Bucketname))

def percent_cb(complete, total):
    sys.stdout.write('.')
    sys.stdout.flush()


k = Key(bucket)
k.key = 'fileName
k.set_contents_from_filename(testfile,
    cb=percent_cb, num_cb=10)
```

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me without having to specify a region:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')
client.upload_file('foo.txt', 'my-bucket', 'foo.txt')
```

However, you can also specify a region when connecting to S3:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3', region_name = 'ap-southeast-2')
client.upload_file('foo.txt', 'my-bucket', 'foo.txt')
```

By the way, you should **never** have a need to put credentials in a source (.py) file. Instead, store credentials in a configuration file. The SDK will automatically retrieve them. The easiest way to create the file is with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) [`aws configure` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html).

Then, you can just run code like mine above, without having to worry about passing credentials.

Comment: i found the solution in below mentioned  link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454559/unable-to-connect-aws-s3-bucket-using-boto .thank for your response.